# How can I select from a raw string in objection orm

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js, objection.js

I am trying to run a query from the results of another using with in the objection orm

ex:

```
Model.query().with(alias, query).select(columns).from(alias);
```

according to the [Knex documentation](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-with) which is linked from the [objection docs](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/query-builder/find-methods.html#with), this should work fine. However, when I run the code, objection prepends the schema name to the alias and I get an error stating that `relation schema.alias does not exist`. I tried using `raw` but this did not help either.

ex:

```
Model.query().with(alias, query).select(columns).from(raw(alias));
```

is there a way for me to select the table/alias defined in the `with` method without objection prepending the schema to it?

Answer (score 0):

The query method of the model I was using was overridden with code that specified the schema

ex:

```
class MyModel extends BaseModel {
  static query() {
     return super.query().withSchema(schema);
  }
}
```

To get around this issue I used the query method of the parent class directly rather than the overridden query method of the model I was using.

This solves my current problem, but does not answer the question of whether one could omit the prepended schema name in the `from` method.